# Pop Up not function correctly in iPad safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I have a code segment which opens a pop up once the button is clicked.This is done using JavaScript and jQuery. But unfortunately the pop up does not load in Ipad. The pop up loads in earlier versions in iPad. But with the latest versions (8.1) the Popup loads with a blank content.

```
    $("[id$='ViewButton']").click(function(){    
    loadPopup();
});


function loadPopup(){
//loads popup only if it is disabled
if(popupStatus==0){
    $("#backgroundPopup1").css({
        "opacity": "0.5"
    });
    $("#backgroundPopup1").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#popupContacts").fadeIn("slow");
    popupStatus = 1;
}
}
```

Please share with me any prior experience on this as I am new on this.

Pop Up not function correctly in iPad safari browser

Answer (score 1):

Try using fadeTo() instead of fadeIn().

eg.,

```
$("#backgroundPopup1").fadeTo("slow", 0.5); // '0.5' refers to opacity level.
$("#popupContacts").fadeTo("slow", 1);
```